# Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/datetimepicker" from "node_modules\react-native-modal-datetime-picker\src\DateTimePickerModal.android.js"

Tags: react-native, datetime, datetimepicker

**I am using expo**

I have the following error:

Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/datetimepicker" from "node_modules\react-native-modal-datetime-picker\src\DateTimePickerModal.android.js"
ERROR  [Error: undefined Unable to resolve module @react-native-community/datetimepicker from F:\CODEBLOCKS\android studio\class_finder\node_modules\react-native-modal-datetime-picker\src\DateTimePickerModal.android.js: @react-native-community/datetimepicker could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules

> 3 | import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
> |                             ^

---

I have tried everything to solve it ....I have tried many solves from stack overflow solutions. But none have worked . Is there any alternative way to use datetimepicker ?

I have tried following command to solve this

```
npm i react-native-modal-datetime-picker @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```

```
expo install react-native-modal-datetime-picker @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```